# Missing type in composite literal

Tags: struct, go

```
type A struct {
    B struct {
        Some string
        Len  int
    }
}
```

Simple question. How to initialize this struct? I would like to do something like this:

```
a := &A{B:{Some: "xxx", Len: 3}}
```

Expectedly I'm getting an error:

```
missing type in composite literal
```

Sure, I can create a separated struct B and initialize it this way:

```
type Btype struct {
    Some string
    Len int
}

type A struct {
    B Btype
}

a := &A{B:Btype{Some: "xxx", Len: 3}}
```

But it not so useful than the first way. Is there a shortcut to initialize anonymous structure?

Comment: @silasdavis common, it was 2013

Comment: I got this error while trying to set a value to a pointer, rather than a memory address, inside a composite struct literal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [assignability rules](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) are forgiving for anonymous types which leads to another possibility where you can retain the original definition of `A` while allowing short composite literals of that type to be written. If you really insist on an anonymous type for the `B` field, I would probably write something like:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type (
        A struct {
                B struct {
                        Some string
                        Len  int
                }
        }

        b struct {
                Some string
                Len  int
        }
)

func main() {
        a := &A{b{"xxx", 3}}
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/5tkQ4R98kJ)

---

Output

```
&main.A{B:struct { Some string; Len int }{Some:"xxx", Len:3}}
```

Comment: this fails if a field value is slice of struct

Answer (score 10):

do it this way:

```
type Config struct {
    Element struct {    
        Name string 
        ConfigPaths []string 
    } 
}
```

```
config = Config{}
config.Element.Name = "foo"
config.Element.ConfigPaths = []string{"blah"}
```

Comment: this fails if a field value is slice of struct

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler imo:

```golang
type A struct {
    B struct {
        Some string
        Len  int
    }
}

a := A{
    struct {
        Some string
        Len  int
    }{"xxx", 3},
}
fmt.Printf("%+v", a)
```