# "Missing type in composite literal" for anonymous list of maps in struct

Tags: go

**Edit**: While the compilation error in [Missing type in composite literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912893/missing-type-in-composite-literal) is the same as that in my question, they were different enough in composition for me to not understand how I would apply the solution to my program, hence the creation of this question.

I am new to go, and I am trying to write a test for a function which I have verified can successfully can be called like so:

```
func main() {

    items := []map[string]int{
        map[string]int{
            "value": 100,
            "weight": 5,
        },
        map[string]int{
            "value": 90,
            "weight": 2,
        },
        map[string]int{
            "value": 80,
            "weight": 2,
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(KnapSack(items, 0, 6))
}
```

Using this template (generated by my IDE) for convenience:

```
func TestKnapSack(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        items            []map[string]int
        current_index    int
        remaining_weight int
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want int
    }{
        {
            "Only test", // name of test
            {
                {   // items
                    map[string]int{
                        "value": 100,
                        "weight": 5,
                    },
                    map[string]int{
                        "value": 90,
                        "weight": 2,
                    },
                    map[string]int{
                        "value": 80,
                        "weight": 2,
                    },
                },
                0, // current_index
                4, // remaining_weight
            },
            170, // want
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := KnapSack(tt.args.items, tt.args.current_index, tt.args.remaining_weight); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("KnapSack() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The `args` struct does not like my array of maps. How can I fill this struct so that it will compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing type in composite literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912893/missing-type-in-composite-literal)

Comment: You can only elide types for map, slice or array elements.  The type is required for the `args` struct field and the `items` struct field.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I Was missing the type for `args`, which made adding the type for `[]map[string]int` not fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @zerkms I saw several questions with a similar title to mine and was not able to figure out what was wrong with my program based on those answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you miss the type of `args` and `[]map[string]int`

```golang
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want int
    }{
        {
            "Only test", // name of test
            args{
                []map[string]int{   // items
                    map[string]int{
                        "value": 100,
                        "weight": 5,
                    },
                    map[string]int{
                        "value": 90,
                        "weight": 2,
                    },
                    map[string]int{
                        "value": 80,
                        "weight": 2,
                    },
                },
                0, // current_index
                4, // remaining_weight
            },
            170, // want
        },
    }
```