# Generating nested JSON with golang

Tags: go

So what am I doing wrong here, am not really understanding how to generate a nested JSON structure:

I am getting "missing type in composite literal" exception.
https://play.golang.org/p/pA1fpbQHbb0

```
package main

import "fmt"

type FamilyRequestBody struct {
    Family string `json:"family"`
}

type DataRequestBody struct {
    Family FamilyRequestBody `json:"family"`
}

type EventRequestBody struct {
    Account string `json:"account"`
    Player  string `json:"player"`
    Count   int    `json:"count"`
}

type TeamRequestBody struct {
    Account string `json:"account"`
    Team    string `json:"team"`
}

type PlayerRequestBody struct {
    Account string          `json:"account"`
    Team    string          `json:"team"`
    Player  string          `json:"player"`
    Data    DataRequestBody `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    l := PlayerRequestBody{
        Account: "my-account",
        Team:    "12345",
        Player:  "23424234",
        Data:    {Family: "12345"},
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", l)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17912893/13860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty straight forward, you definded it like this:

```
type PlayerRequestBody struct {
    Account string          `json:"account"`
    Team    string          `json:"team"`
    Player  string          `json:"player"`
    Data    DataRequestBody `json:"data"`

 l := PlayerRequestBody{
        Account: "my-account",
        Team:    "12345",
        Player:  "23424234",
        Data:    DataRequestBody{FamilyRequestBody{Family:"hello"}},
    }
```

but wanted it to use it like that:

```
type PlayerRequestBody struct {
    Account string           `json:"account"`
    Team    string           `json:"team"`
    Player  string           `json:"player"`
    Data    FamilyRequestBody`json:"family"`

 l := PlayerRequestBody{
        Account: "my-account",
        Team:    "12345",
        Player:  "23424234",
        Data:    {Family:"hello"}},
    }
```

Your field `Data` is from type `DataRequestBody` like defined in your struct, you cant put another struct there. In golang there is no such thing as inheritance, and that is probably not what you wanted either.

I agree that OP´s question is not JSON related, like Flimzy mentioned in the comments, but i leave the links for good measures.

If that is not what you wanted, check out the many other questions explaining how json with go works, or use [gobyexample](https://gobyexample.com/json), or the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

Comment: The question (and thus answer) really has nothing to do with JSON, so suggesting the OP search for other JSON questions, and linking to JSON-related docs, isn't really the best advice.

Comment: Your answer isn't per se wrong, but it's incomplete. Please show the full definition you're referring to. And best practice would also be to use a named field in `DataRequestBody`.

Comment: This is how I have progressed, but am still not getting it what's wrong...

https://play.golang.org/p/g3WS4BnGquY

Comment: @Artur Dont define a stuct in another struct, its not idiomatic.

Comment: @sHartmann this was just to illustrate, won't do that in final code

Comment: @hartmann I am still stuck with this issue. All I want to do is make with json.Marshal to look like this:

{
   account: "foo",
   team: "bar",
   player: "John",
   data: {
      family: "Doe"
   } 
}

I am just not understanding on how to create the nested json structure with Structs.

Comment: @hartmann I gave acceptance to your answer. Thank you for your help. I managed to get it working when I read your answer little bit more.