# How to make a HTTP post data request

Tags: go

```
func send_msg(msg string, user string) {
    url := "https://test.com/"

    token := "Bearer " + get_token()

    header := req.Header{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": token,
    }

    // this string param can not use variable user and msg.
    // param := `{
    //  "email": "jjjj@gmail.com",
    //  "msg_type": "text",
    //  "content": { "text": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa" }
    // }`

    // this req.Param param error：missing type in composite literal
    param := req.Param{
        "email": user,
        "msg_type": "text",
        "content": {  "text" :  msg  }, 
    }
    r,_ := req.Post(url, header,  param)
    resp := r.String()
    log.Println(resp)

}
```

This req.Param param error：missing type in composite literal

This string param can not use variable user and msg.

How can I use variable param?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing type in composite literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912893/missing-type-in-composite-literal)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `"net/http"`, The Post function expects `url`, `content-type` and `body` in that order. Link : [net/http#post](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Post)
Thus, for your particular case, it should look something like this

```
    url := "https://test.com/"
    contentType := "application/json"
    param := []byte(`{"email": user, "msg_type": "text","content": {  "text" :  "msg"  }, }`)
    resp, err := http.Post(url, contentType, bytes.NewBuffer(param))
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        //handle error
    } else {

        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        log.Println(body)
    }
```

If you want to add custom headers, you may use [newRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) which gives you `req` and then you can add or set custom headers .

```
req.Headers.Set(existingHeaderWithNewValue)
req.Headers.Add(customHeader)
```